# EnableOAuth2Sso simultaneously for multiple social networks

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-cloud

I am implementing a spring boot application that needs to provide OAuth2 token authorization and support multiple social services (google+, facebook etc). The user should be able to select his preferred social network and sign-in using the OAuth2 authorization framework.
I am implementing the above using the approach described here http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/.

Currently my application.yml looks like this

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: {{my app's google id}
      clientSecret: {{my app's google secret code}} 
  etc...
```

Also, the spring boot main class is annotated as @EnableOAuth2Sso.

My problem is that with the above approach I can only use one social network for my purposes (google+ in the example). So, I would like to know if there is a way to support, simultaneously, multiple social networks by defining them somehow in the .yml file. 
Is this possible or should I use another approach?

thanks for your time,

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@EnableOAuth2Sso` feature wasn't designed to support multiple providers as simple YAML declarations. Instead of using that you need to install 2 separate `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilters` in your security configuration, each with a different login path, and then link to them from a UI.

Comment: I've a similar requirement and planning to have an AngularJS front-end, as well as mobo client in future. Am confused whether to go this way, or to use Spring Social. it could be very helpful to know how both would compare.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and your awesome spring projects/modules) Dave! I made some experiments using `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` with the rest template `OAuth2RestTemplate` based on `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails` but I can't get the token in the final step of the OAuth2 dance. I will try to complete the code based on this approach though. 
Another question related to the annotation is: how can I use another port for the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` to work with (e.g. 9000)?

Comment: @Sanjay what is your thoughts on the Spring-Social? I am trying to use it but it seems very unstable. I had problems on running the codes from the official Documentation and from github!

Comment: Sometime back I had tried it for Facebook, and it found it working well (https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-boot-security-social-sample). But I too got a feeling that the project was moving slowly. It seems like important bugs are remaining open for long. This one for example - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SOCIAL-448

Comment: Yesterday I cloned and run your project! it is the only one that I managed to work with and modify, thanks for this! 
After having problems  even on using the official examples I am scared on using the Spring-Social package on my own projects. I fell like the project was created to allow the programmers to implement the "Connect to Facebook" functionality in 5 lines of code, but if one needs anything else the problems begin.

Comment: To me it feels like the Spring team may not be being able to give enough attention to moving the project forward. Maybe @Dave would be able to get us some comments from the project leads on the activeness of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, please check the link posted by Mario (not sure why it was downvoted..): [social_login_manual](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual)

The link says that @EnableOAuth2Sso is essentially a combination of @EnableOAuth2Client and some additional magic. The downside is you can't easily customize its behavior to support multiple providers. Thus in the tutorial it is suggested to replace it with @EnableOAuth2Client instead and go by repeating what @EnableOAuth2Sso does under the hood with some custom additions.

So, here is how it looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   private Filter ssoFilter() {
      CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
      List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
      filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
      filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
      filter.setFilters(filters);
      return filter;
    }



 private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
      OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
      OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
      filter.setRestTemplate(template);
      filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
          client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId()));
      return filter;
    }

  @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
      return new ClientResources();
    }

  @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
      return new ClientResources();
    }
```

}

```
class ClientResources {

  @NestedConfigurationProperty
  private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

  @NestedConfigurationProperty
  private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

  public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
    return client;
  }

  public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
    return resource;
  }
}

facebook:
  client:
    clientId: 233668646673605
    clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
    accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    tokenName: oauth_token
    authenticationScheme: query
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
github:
  client:
    clientId: bd1c0a783ccdd1c9b9e4
    clientSecret: 1a9030fbca47a5b2c28e92f19050bb77824b5ad1
    accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this and many other questions about multiple authentication provider support. Syer's answer that core `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation wasn't designed for this was actually very helpful. It made me look elsewhere.

Benefiting from Nimbus OAuth library I designed another approach. It probably isn't clean and nice, but it does what I was planning. Separate authentication providers are defined in properties and selected based on URI path.

This is what I came up with: https://bitbucket.org/klaalo/orcidconnect/src/f3e4fada9827e47bd33efd579fd020c41e37ee2a/src/main/java/fi/csc/orcidconnect/oauth2client/

Basically, a provider is selected based on a decision made by `DelegatingAuthenticationProviderEndpoint` in SecurityConfiguration (on default package). `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is waiting for authentication events and making redirects to authentication providers. On return it will validate received code and carries `AuthenticationToken` for custom `AuthenticationProvider` to evaluate.

Received UserDetails are persisted to User object in a Map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may want to edit to highlight few section to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided only shows how to use the @EnableOAuth2Sso facilities that enables a single Authentication Server provider. In order to implement multiple providers you should follow :

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual

and implement a filter for each provider.