# How do I dynamically specify OAuth2 resource details in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, oauth, shopify, spring-security-oauth2

I'm creating an application integrating with Shopify's API, which uses OAuth2 for authentication and authorization.  Using [the tutorial for Spring Security OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/), and [the tutorial for Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth), I've been able to get integration working with a single shop.  The YAML configuration looks like this:

```
shopify:
  shop: myshop
  scopes: read_customers,read_orders
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: myclientid
      clientSecret: mysecret
      tokenName: access_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      accessTokenUri: https://${shopify.shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://${shopify.shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?scope=${shopify.scopes}&grant_options[]=
      pre-established-redirect-uri: https://myapp/login
      registered-redirect-uri: https://myapp/login
      use-current-uri: false
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://${shopify.shop}.myshopify.com/admin/shop.json
```

However, this static configuration won't work for an app published in Shopify's App Store because the redirect, access token, user info, and user authorization URIs depend on the shop name.  [There are examples of using more than one provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512401/enableoauth2sso-simultaneously-for-multiple-social-networks/40274971#40274971), but they still have to be static.

To allow these URI's to be dynamic, I've come up with a few possible options:

1. Use a parameter in the `/login` path to identify the shop, then create a filter that adds the shop name to a `ThreadLocal` that runs before everything else, then dynamically create the `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails` that is needed by the OAuth2 filter via a Spring proxied factory bean.
2. Use a sort of "metafilter" that dynamically recreates the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` per request along with all of the resources that it needs.
3. Override `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` so that it can handle recreating the `RestTemplate` it needs to obtain the access token.

All of these options seem pretty difficult.  What's a good way to handle dynamically-generated URI's for access tokens and user information in Spring Security OAuth2?

Also, since I'm new to OAuth2 in general, do I need to enable a Resource Server in my Spring configuration to protect my app with the access token?

Comment: Hi @Brad, I have a similar issue. Have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: Sadly, only theoretically.  It would require some pretty significant changes to how the library works; what the `@EnableOAuthSso` annotation gives you is really only good for static sites.  You'd have to create new classes and wire up the beans to do things differently.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this.  Have you made any progress?  I'll see if I can put something together.

Comment: Not as of present.  I've been struggling trying to get Spring Security to give me a Principal with the Shopify information I need (like merchant name, for example), so I haven't had the time to look at this.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but I did return a dynamic url for an oauth resource by overriding the getter for the Oauth2ProtectedResource

```
    @Bean(name = "googleOauthResource")
public BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails getGoogleOauthResource() {
    final AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails() {
        @Override
        public String getPreEstablishedRedirectUri() {
            final RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
            if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
                final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
                return request.getRequestURL() + "?" + request.getQueryString() + "&addStuff";
            }

            return super.getPreEstablishedRedirectUri();
        }
    };
    details.setId("google-oauth-client");
    details.setClientId("xxxxxxxxxxx");
    details.setClientSecret("xxxxxxxx");
    details.setAccessTokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");
    details.setTokenName("authorization_code");
    details.setScope(Arrays.asList("https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"));
    details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/xxx-api-web/v2/gmail"); //TODO
    details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
    details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
    details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
    details.setGrantType("authorization_code");
    return details;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem you are and I'm leaning toward your first theory of using ThreadLocal storage.  Here is how I'll probably go about my solution:

Set values from ServletRequest in LocalThread storage by overriding methods in OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter:

- attemptAuthentication
- successfulAuthentication
- unsuccessfulAuthentication
- requiresAuthentication

Then translate the URI's within the OAuth2RestTemplate by overriding the followign methods:

- createRequest
- doExecute
- appendQueryParameter

I'll probably have to make my own @Bean for the RestTemplate that has an injected @Service that will lookup the dynamic Shopify domain.

I'll post my solution if it works.