# Spring Security OAuth2: How do I provide two seperate login links for two type of users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am creating a web app, which has two type of users, say A and B. Currently, the login flow is like this,

1. There is single login link on `index.html`, which points to `/login`
2. The user is redirected to google login page, where user logins and is redirected to `index.html`
3. At this point, I have to verify whether the user is authenticated and if yes, what is the type of user (A, B or new user), the further process is then to redirect them to appropriate links.

The type of the user is decided based upon whether an entry exists in two tables, one for A and one for B.

The code looks like this,

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
    }
}
```

---

I'd like to simplify this process, wherein,

1. There are two login links, say `/login-A` and `/login-B`
2. The user clicks one of them, gets redirected to Google, authenticates, and redirects to the appropriate page.

Comment: How would you know the user type (A or B) before login ? Don't you need them to login first ? Your current flow makes sense. Also, how is your process simplified with 2 links instead of one ?

Comment: @KeatsPeeks Lets say I have cats and dogs as users, so cats will click on "Login as cat" and dogs will click on "Login as dog". This way, it will be implicit what type of user one is. This way, I don't need to ask a user after login. Just one step less, and also less logic on frontend.

Comment: You can try with using a lower level annotation '@EnableOAuth2Client' in place of '@EnableOAuth2Sso'. But it requires a bit more code. Refer this tutorial - http://www.littlebigextra.com/spring-boot-oauth2-tutorial-for-authorizing-through-facebook-google-linkedin-and-twitter/

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle redirection to different pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `@EnableOAuth2Client` in place of `@EnableOAuth2Sso`, you would be able to define multiple OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.

Your configuration would be something like ..

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

 @RequestMapping("/user")
 public Principal user(Principal principal) {
 return principal;
 }

 // @formatter:off
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.antMatcher("/**")
 .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
 .authorizeRequests()
 .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
 .permitAll()
 .anyRequest()
 .authenticated()
 .and()
 .logout()
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
 .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
 }
 // @formatter:on

 private Filter ssoFilter() {

 CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
 List filters = new ArrayList<>();

 OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilterA = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
 "/login/googleA");
 OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplateA = new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleA(), oauth2ClientContext);
 googleFilterA.setRestTemplate(googleTemplateA);
 tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), googleA().getClientId());
 tokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleTemplateA);
 googleFilterA.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

 OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilterB = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
 "/login/googleB");
 OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplateB = new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleB(), oauth2ClientContext);
 googleFilterB.setRestTemplate(googleTemplateB);
 tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), googleB().getClientId());
 tokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleTemplateB);
 googleFilterB.setTokenServices(tokenServices);



 filters.add(googleFilterA);
 filters.add(googleFilterB);

 filter.setFilters(filters);

 return filter;
 }

 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
 FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
 registration.setFilter(filter);
 registration.setOrder(-100);
 return registration;
 }



 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("google.clientA")
 public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails googleA() {
 return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
 }

 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("google.resource")
 public ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
 return new ResourceServerProperties();
 }


 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("google.clientB")
 public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails googleB() {
 return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
 }
 }
```

And you will define following properties in your application.yml file

```
google:
  clientA:
    clientId: 12894100090-tqso3lih5o42isneort886la2pesafmp.apps.googleusercontent.com
    clientSecret: 9xfU16efvxQ-BTMsXT9wOLpw
    accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    scope: profile email
    redirect-uri: http://yourapp.com/pathA
  clientB:
    clientId: 12894100090-tqso3lih5o42isneort886la2pesafmp.apps.googleusercontent.com
    clientSecret: 9xfU16efvxQ-BTMsXT9wOLpw
    accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    scope: profile email drive
    redirect-uri: http://yourapp.com/pathB
  resource:
    userInfoUri:  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
```

Your index.html will have two links `/login/googleA` and `/login/googleB` for the two types of users.

Refer following tutorials for more details.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

http://www.littlebigextra.com/spring-boot-oauth2-tutorial-for-authorizing-through-facebook-google-linkedin-and-twitter/

**Update -**

For redirecting to different pages you can extend `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class for the two clients like..

```
    class GoogleAAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
            super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            // here you can redirect to whatever location you want to

        }

    }

class GoogleBAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
            super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            // here you can redirect to whatever location you want to

        }

    }
```

And use the extended classes

```
OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilterA = new GoogleAAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
     "/login/googleA");

OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilterB = new GoogleBAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
     "/login/googleB");
```

Comment: It works, except the redirection part. Both link always redirect to homepage(/)

Comment: @Registered User - I have updated my answer to handle redirection to different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's possible, but requires more configuration effort comparing to a single `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation. When this annotation is used it applies `SsoSecurityConfigurer` which registers dedicated `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` with login page path from `OAuth2SsoProperties` (`/login` by default)  for given pattern (`/**` in your case). However it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512401/enableoauth2sso-simultaneously-for-multiple-social-networks) to have multiple `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and `OAuth2SsoProperties` classes in the same application. So you need to manually register multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with corresponding `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter`  with different login pages/patterns/authorization logic for each type of users.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Configure Spring Security Configuration file 
2 - Write Custom Authentication Success Handler class

```
 <user name="userA" password="userApass" authorities="ROLE_A" />
 <user name="userB" password="userBpass" authorities="ROLE_B" />

 protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isUserA = false;
        boolean isUserB= false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
         = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_A")) {
                isUserA = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_B")) {
                isUserB = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isUserA) {
            return "/pageA.html";
        } else if (isUserB) {
            return "/pageB.html";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
```